# Postfix status = deferred

Tags: linux, email, postfix

In an effort to prevent spam I am trying to remove fake or bad e-mails from our database. One of the ways I want to do this is to check the maillog and if an e-mail is not sent then the recipient is removed from the database.

So if the `status=Bounced` this is fine but what about `status=Deferred`? The vast majority of the bad e-mails get the Deferred status. It would be far easier to delete these to but I am not sure if this status could end up deleting good e-mails?

I'd also like to stop postfix trying to re-send deferred e-mails, again I don't know if this will mean legitimate e-mails will not get sent.

I have searched around and can't find a good definition of this status and whether it is likely that a deferred e-mail will end up getting sent a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Yahoo, if you are getting this error

```
TSS04 - temporarily deferred due to user complaints
```

It means, you are sending more emails than your IP and Sending domain reputation allows. Yahoo allows only 100 mails/day approx for a new IP address before giving that error TSS04, The number might change based on your content and sending domain. Its better to warm up your IP slowly and build your reputation.

This thread might be useful to you,
https://serverfault.com/a/1016122/549576

Answer (score 2):

Terminating deferred e-mails can have unforeseen consequences.

For example, since almost 1 year, in the case of Yahoo most of the times e-mails are being deferred unless they are very few in numbers (like under a dozen / day). If there are a few dozens /day they get deferred if coming from a good server (that even has DKIM and its not listed anywhere) other than the very big ones (gmail, etc).

In such a case they are not bad e-mails, they are just delayed by Yahoo. Of course no support even answered such problems. Probably they just keep everything running and that's it. The point is you may want to check things out per domain, not as a general approach.

Install a tool of log statistics centralization and then you can have a clear view on what's bad and what can be still useful.

Comment: You are right it is mainly Yahoo addresses, also in the log is "temporarily deferred due to user complaints". Are you saying these may eventually get through?

Comment: Yes, depending on the volume they can get through after minutes or hours. If they are too many they will not make it and get eventually rejected (after 24 or 48h).

Comment: That doesn't seem to makes sense if it is deferred due to user complaints though. Why would that kind of status change?

Comment: The Yahoo description is incorrect. It's just a default error line, nothing to do with compaints.

Comment: Then why are so many e-mails getting deferred like this? It happens every time to every Yahoo address.

Comment: Because Yahoo is broken. They only keep the e-mail service alive because there are still payed subscribers.